# why do some questions have yellow backgrounds?

Tags: discussion

It's probably a silly question, but it's bothering me nonetheless.  Why do some of the questions in the WordPress stack exchange have a yellow background?  What does that mean?

Comment: You mean those in the list that are matching your favorite tags? :)

Comment: That's what it is?  Cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions which are matching for your favorite tags are displayed with yellow background color.